# CSS pixel shifting issue. Page shifting to some pixels and then back normal

Tags: css

I have some problem in CSS. [Check this page](http://www.papelcouture.com/themes.html).  If you click "Barcelona" link in that page you can see the whole page shifting to 10 pixels right and come back to normal. Why its happening? Any help? Thanks

Comment: No such problem when viewing your website with newest Chrome version. Which browser did you use when you noticed the error?

Comment: I'm using chrome. Maybe goto [this page](http://www.papelcouture.com/themes.html) and click any products. You can see it

Comment: There is also no problem in Firefox 5 or IE9.

Comment: @tw16 Goto [this page](http://www.papelcouture.com/themes.html) and click any products.

Comment: You keep linking the same page as your in your question. I have been to the link. I think I see what you mean. Are you sure you are not just seeing the page move because the scrollbar disappears when you go to a product page?

Comment: Resolution is also a factor here... I assume you have a high resolution monitor, @Viruthagiri?

Comment: @everyone Hey guys Litex's answer fixed it. Thanks everyone. Upvoted everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shifts because of vertical scrollbar showing up. Also the image corresponding to "barcelona" shows in wrong place in firefox. Maybe the old images isn't removed before next one shows, and that forces it to be displayed below?

Apart from the image positioning, a good thing is have `overflow-y:scroll` set on `html`. It will force the scrollbar to be always visible (I know maybe not the nicest look) but in exchange the page won't be shifting when navigating to different pages (some may be long, and thus scrollbar shows, some not and have no scrollbar)

Answer (score 1):

Image which is loaded when you click "Barcelona" is wider than it's container. You either reduce width of that image or make the image container a bit wider.